# Using C++ splitting a section string which is in "[General Setting]" format

Tags: c++

I am new to C++, i want to read ini file which has section and key - value pair.
Depending on the section, i want to read the value for corresponding key.
Primarily, i want to read the section which is enclosed in square brackets.
Please help. 
Thank you.

Comment: can you give an example of the string format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For real INI file parsing, I highly suggest the [iniparser library](http://ndevilla.free.fr/iniparser/). It is excellently documented and easy to use in both C *and* C++ programs.

If you are only interested in parsing strings of the form `[Section name]`, you could do the following: Find first '[' and last ']' for the string and mark the positions. If both characters have been found, take the section name to be substring between the positions you identified.

Assuming you are using an `std::string`, you can do the following:

```cpp
std::string myString = " [Section name] ";

std::size_t start = myString.find_first_of( '[' );
std::size_t end   = myString.find_last_of( ']' );

std::string sectionName;
if( start != std::string::npos && end != std::string::npos )
{
  sectionName = myString.substr(start + 1, end - 1);
}

std::cout << sectionName << std::endl;
```

Comment: Nice library, now we just need a C++ wrapper to have RAII goodness and strong typing :)

Comment: @MatthieuM. +1 for something that's all too true. I have been using it for some projects in the past and always wrote at least some kind of wrapper functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet should show you the basic logic for parsing an ini file and skipping # or ; prefixed lines which are treated as comments

this needs sanity checks for group names, names and values, but should suffice as a demonstration:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
//
//   a simple ini file parser (doesn't check for validity of name field length wise or if it has = char
//   to demonstrate basic parsing
//
class IniFile
{
public:
    enum { MAX_LINE_LEN = 10*1024 };
    class MalformedInputException : public std::exception
    {
    public:
        const char* what() const throw() { return "Input is not a valid or well formed ini file"; }
    };
    typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> Properties;
    IniFile(){}
    virtual ~IniFile(){}

    std::istream& load(std::istream& in)
    {
        char lineBuffer[MAX_LINE_LEN];
        std::string curGroup = "";
        while(!in.eof())
        {
            in.getline(lineBuffer, MAX_LINE_LEN);
            //std::cout<<"line buffer : {"<<lineBuffer<<"}"<<std::endl;
            std::string line = trim(lineBuffer);
            //std::cout<<"trimmed : {"<<line<<"}"<<std::endl;
            // we process only non-empty / non-comment lines
            if(line.size() > 0 && line[0] != '#' && line[0] != ';')
            {
                if(line[0] == '[' && line[line.size() - 1] == ']')
                {
                    curGroup = trim(line.substr(1, line.size() - 2));
                }
                else if(curGroup.size() > 0)
                {
                    size_t index = line.find_first_of('=');
                    //todo: needs checks for valid name=value format here
                    Properties& props = m_props[curGroup]; // this will create new Properties if none exists
                    props[line.substr(0,index)] = line.substr(index+1);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw MalformedInputException();
                }

            }
        }
        return in;
    }
    std::ostream& save(std::ostream& os) const
    {
        std::map<std::string, Properties>::const_iterator iter = m_props.begin();
        while(iter != m_props.end())
        {
            os<<"["<<iter->first<<"]"<<std::endl;
            Properties::const_iterator propIter = iter->second.begin();
            while(propIter != iter->second.end())
            {
                os<<propIter->first<<"="<<propIter->second<<std::endl;
                propIter++;
            }
            iter++;
        }
        return os;
    }
    std::string trim(const std::string& input)
    {
        static std::string WHITESPACES = "\r\n \t\b\a";
        if(input.size() == 0){ return input; }
        else
        {
            size_t start = 0;

            for(size_t index = 0; index < input.size(); index++)
            {
                if(WHITESPACES.find(input[index]) < WHITESPACES.size())
                {
                    start = index;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            size_t endIndex = input.size() - 1;
            if(start == endIndex){ return ""; }
            for(; endIndex > start; endIndex--)
            {
                char c = input.at(endIndex);
                if(WHITESPACES.find_first_of(c) >= WHITESPACES.size())
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            size_t length = endIndex - start + 1;
            return input.substr(start, length);
        }
    }
private:
    std::map<std::string, Properties> m_props;
};


inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const IniFile& iniFile)
{
    return iniFile.save(os);
}
inline std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& in, IniFile& iniFile)
{
    return iniFile.load(in);
}
#include <sstream>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss<<"# sample ini file"<<std::endl;
    ss<<"[Group1]"<<std::endl;
    ss<<"foo=bar    \n"<<std::endl;
    ss<<"baz=foz"<<std::endl;
    ss<<"; this is another comment"<<std::endl;
    ss<<"[Group2]"<<std::endl;
    ss<<"blanga=kukoo"<<std::endl;

    std::string buf = ss.str();
    std::istringstream sin(buf);

    IniFile iniFile;
    iniFile.load(sin);

    iniFile.save(std::cout<<"Ini File Loaded : "<<std::endl);
    return 0;
}
```